# How to write as a Neko Character

Tags: creative-writing, fan-fiction

So my character is a Neko, which is half human and half cat, and I use her a lot in fighting scenes and I was wondering if anyone really knows how one could write that out, I assume that the fighting would have feline like characteristics and that's where I struggle, if anyone has any tips please let me know

Comment: The best tip in such a situation is always to look at how other people are doing it. Have you looked through your favourite manga / anime / fan-fiction to see how people are writing fighting cat-human characters? Pick your favourite style, try to emulate that a bit and change the things you don't like. Just an example I can think of right now: Naruto, who has a fox spirit inside him, fights on all four at some point (I think when Kyuubi takes over for a while with four tails).

Comment: I remember seeing that for a few cat characters, too. Many animal charcters are also blood-thirsty in their fighting style, losing their "human" character traits. Look at Omamori Himari (cat) or Inuyasha (dog) for example. Those are things that you should look out for and then see what parts fit your personal style and which don't. We can't answer what you should do specifically, that depends on how you want to portray your character and the story you are writing. You can just choose something completely different if you want.

Comment: My first instinct is to say, "Just write it." Try it out. You chose that character and their characteristics, so it's up to you to figure out how to write them. If it's too hard or if something's not working, you can change their characteristics. It's all up to you. (But also, read a lot and see how others do it.)

Comment: Do you have in mind a humanoid cat, which would fight with her own claws and teeth, or a cat-styled human, like Batman's [Catwoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catwoman)?

Answer (score 2):

The best bet you have is looking directly at the source material - e.g., real felines fighting. Of course it would help narrowing down to one species (the domestic cat is very different, in terms of survival instincts, from the african lion). 
If you lived with a couple of cats, you should have a good idea of how they fight and how they spar. If you don't, well, luckily the internet obsession with felines should come in handy (go check youtube).

What traits of feline behaviour should come over to your "neko" character is ultimately up to you and to your worldbuilding. From where your neko people come from? What are their survival habits - e.g., how did they live before becoming fully sentient, self aware beings? In what way their anatomy is different from the regular human?

E.g. us humans come from apes, and apes are highly social animals. As a result, the early hominids lived and hunted in groups, and still now, a human (homo sapiens sapiens) being suffers without a "pack" - ergo someone to form social bonds with. Of course, now we call it family and friends, but our society evolved from the basic need of sharing our life with someone similar to us.

So, your neko people might undergo similar or totally different paths. This influences the fighting as well: sometimes packs of female lions hunt together, while other felines hunt alone. This will influence the fighting style - a lone cat has to secure the kill by himself, while a group can be more "specialized".

Another thing is: make the anatomy of your cat people make sense (as much as it's possible). If they are humans with tails and ears, don't make them fight and run on all fours! The human anatomy is not made for squatting down, less so for running like an animal. It would be different if, for example, your neko people would have longer or differently developed legs.

You could take this the other way around, deciding which traits you want and then working backwards to get a reasonable worldbuilding explanation for it.

My two cents:

- Make your cat people go for the throat. It's an universal weak spot and who manages to hit it first basically wins. In a fight, you'll often see felines jumping at each other throaths - in order to deal damage or just assert dominance. In the same way, big cats like lions (who can deal a lot of damage with their claws) usually rely on their bite to strike the killing blow on their prey.
- Avoid anything that's bigger than you, kill everything that's smaller - pretty much the domestic cat way of life.

Comment: what feline like attributes do the Thunder cats have?  aside from agility?  i would say nothing.

Comment: @dolphin_of_france And that's a perfectly fine answer. But then again there is no reason to make them behave or fight like cats, if it's just made for aesthetic purposes.